# How to use `@task` decorator in Airflow to return outputs from wrapped function

Tags: python, airflow

I'm confused how the `@task` decorator is supposed to be used in Airflow when working with large amounts of data.

For most situations where I work with data, I am typically dealing with several transformations of that data. I use various assorted methods for this and the methods I use typically have an output.

```py
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

# Load the pre-trained ResNet-50 model
model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

# Create a tensor representing an image
image_tensor = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)

# Define the transformation to apply to the image tensor
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                         std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

# Apply the transformation to the image tensor
input_tensor = transform(image_tensor)

# Pass the input tensor through the pre-trained model
output_tensor = model(input_tensor)
```

This is an example of the kind of transformation I'm referring to.

The problem I'm having with airflow is that the `@task` decorator appears to wrap all the outputs of my functions and makes their output value of type `PlainXComArgs`.

But consider the following

> Knowing the size of the data you are passing between Airflow tasks is important when deciding which implementation method to use. As you'll learn, XComs are one method of passing data between tasks, but they are only appropriate for small amounts of data. Large data sets require a method making use of intermediate storage and possibly utilizing an external processing framework.

and also

> XComs should be used to pass small amounts of data between tasks. For example, task metadata, dates, model accuracy, or single value query results are all ideal data to use with XCom.
>
> While there is nothing stopping you from passing small data sets with XCom, be very careful when doing so. This is not what XCom was designed for, and using it to pass data like pandas dataframes can degrade the performance of your DAGs and take up storage in the metadata database.
>
> XCom cannot be used for passing large data sets between tasks. The limit for the size of the XCom is determined by which metadata database you are using:
>
> Postgres: 1 Gb
>
> SQLite: 2 Gb
>
> MySQL: 64 Kb
>
> You can see that these limits aren't very big. And even if you think your data might meet the maximum allowable limit, don't use XComs. Instead, use intermediary data storage, which is more appropriate for larger amounts of data.

Source: https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-passing-data-between-tasks

Based on this, it seems using XCom is a bad idea for many data tasks I'd be considering. The link I mentioned offered some example code for using intermediate storage

```py
from pendulum import datetime, duration
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook

S3_CONN_ID = "aws_conn"
BUCKET = "myexamplebucketone"


@task
def upload_to_s3(cat_fact_number):
    # Instantiate
    s3_hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id=S3_CONN_ID)

    # Base URL
    url = "http://catfact.ninja/fact"

    # Grab data
    res = requests.get(url).json()

    # Convert JSON to csv
    res_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([res])
    res_csv = res_df.to_csv()

    # Take string, upload to S3 using predefined method
    s3_hook.load_string(
        res_csv,
        "cat_fact_{0}.csv".format(cat_fact_number),
        bucket_name=BUCKET,
        replace=True,
    )


@task
def process_data(cat_fact_number):
    """Reads data from S3, processes, and saves to new S3 file"""
    # Connect to S3
    s3_hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id=S3_CONN_ID)

    # Read data
    data = StringIO(
        s3_hook.read_key(
            key="cat_fact_{0}.csv".format(cat_fact_number), bucket_name=BUCKET
        )
    )
    df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")

    # Process data
    processed_data = df[["fact"]]
    print(processed_data)

    # Save processed data to CSV on S3
    s3_hook.load_string(
        processed_data.to_csv(),
        "cat_fact_{0}_processed.csv".format(cat_fact_number),
        bucket_name=BUCKET,
        replace=True,
    )


@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    max_active_runs=1,
    schedule="@daily",
    default_args={"retries": 1, "retry_delay": duration(minutes=1)},
    catchup=False,
)
def intermediary_data_storage_dag():
    upload_to_s3(cat_fact_number=1) >> process_data(cat_fact_number=1)


intermediary_data_storage_dag()
```

However, I notice that this code side-steps the issue I'm focused on because neither functions referenced with the `@task` decorator involve return statements. By contrast, my task below does have a return statement. But as you see, this will create a problem.

```py
import torch
from typing import Optional
from airflow.decorators import task

@task
def generate_normal_vector(k: int, filepath: Optional[str] = None) -> torch.Tensor:
    """
    Generates a vector of length k with normally distributed random numbers.

    Parameters:
    k (int): Length of the vector.
    filepath (str, optional): Path to save the tensor as a file. If None, the tensor is not saved.

    Returns:
    torch.Tensor: A tensor of shape (k,).
    """
    tensor = torch.randn(k)
    if filepath:
        torch.save(tensor, filepath)
    return tensor
```

and I have testing

```
class TestGenerateNormalVector(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_generate_normal_vector_shape(self):
        # Test that the function returns a tensor of the correct shape
        k = 10
        vector = generate_normal_vector(k)
        self.assertEqual(vector.shape, torch.Size([k]))

    def test_generate_normal_vector_values(self):
        # Test that the function generates normally distributed random numbers
        k = 10000
        vector = generate_normal_vector(k)
        mean = vector.mean()
        std = vector.std()
        self.assertAlmostEqual(mean, 0, delta=0.1)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(std, 1, delta=0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run this, I get an error

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_generate_normal_vector_shape (__main__.TestGenerateNormalVector)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...<filepath>...\helper_functions_test.py", line 65, in test_generate_normal_vector_shape
    self.assertEqual(vector.shape, torch.Size([k]))
AttributeError: 'PlainXComArg' object has no attribute 'shape'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_generate_normal_vector_values (__main__.TestGenerateNormalVector)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...<filepath>...\helper_functions_test.py", line 71, in test_generate_normal_vector_values
    mean = vector.mean()
AttributeError: 'PlainXComArg' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

So you can see the problem I have, which is that the `@task` wrapper yields this `PlainXComArg`. So when I try to treat it as a torch tensor, the torch methods don't work. My original functions returned torch tensors and this works without the dectorator. So the problem is that the `@task` decorator is converting them to type `PlainXComArg`.

While I understand I can save every output from all my functions to disk, is it possible to somehow use the `@task` decorator while still returning the outputs of my functions normally?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to answer your question :

> While I understand I can save every output from all my functions to disk, is it possible to somehow use the @task decorator while still returning the outputs of my functions normally?

Xcom has some limitations concerning data types. Here what was said during the Airflow Summit 2021 :

> As it stands, only the following datatypes are supported in Airflow 2.0
>
> - Python native: dict, list, tuple, str, int, long, float, True, False, None
> - Future: Airflow supported objects such as numpy objects, datetime,
>   date, etc
> - For security, pickling is no longer recommended

So you understand that passing tensors isn't possible.

Secondly, I see you're doing deep learning, computer vision precisely, which usually need an enormous amount of data. And as you said :

> XCom cannot be used for passing large data sets between tasks.

Best practices recommend to use intermediate storages like buckets.

What you can do is between each of your deep learning steps download and upload the results to GCS or S3 like you were doing before.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, you can reference name_of_task.function() to get the original method you defined before it was decorated with @task.

I concur with Lucas that you should not return large data sets in XCOM. Instead save the large dataset and return a path or url for that location.